# How can I convert this condition to query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a condition below:

```
Table : user, owner, category, user_sub_category
        inner join user.owner_id = user.id
        inner join user.category_id = category.id
        left join user.id = user_sub_category.lounge_id
        left join user_sub_category.category_id = category.id
```

And now I need to convert them in sql query but I don't know if what I did is right. What I've done so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM db.user
  inner join db.owner
  on  user.owner_id = owner.id
  inner join db.category
  on user.category_id = category.id
  left join db.user_sub_category
  on user.id = user_sub_category.lounge_id
  and user_sub_category.category_id = category.id;
```

Please feel free to correct me. Thanks

Comment: Your query seems right as per your conditions. Test it with some data to check if you getting required output.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM db.user
  inner join db.owner
  on  user.owner_id = owner.id --in condition it says user.id, but if it is owner table, then this is OK
  inner join db.category
  on user.category_id = category.id
  left join db.user_sub_category
  on user.id = user_sub_category.lounge_id
  and user_sub_category.category_id = category.id;
```

It looks fine.